# Odd primes for which sum of three $p$-th powers is the whole $(\mathbb{Z}/p^{2}\mathbb{Z})$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

I am investigating what are the odd primes such that $(x_{1}^{p} + x_{2}^{p} + x_{3}^{p}) \equiv k $ (mod $p^{2}$) for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Right now I am truly stuck.

One of my guesses (all others have failed) was that one of the implications of above would be that $\exists$ some other odd prime $q$ such that

$(x_{1}^{p} + x_{2}^{p} + x_{3}^{p}) \equiv k $ (mod $q$) would not be solvable for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem

Comment: What is the utility of FLT here?

Comment: $$x_1^p+x_2^p+x_3^p\equiv x_1+x_2+x_3\equiv k\pmod p$$ any time the variables on the left are coprime with $p$ then maybe apply Hensel to get it to $p^2$

Comment: I don't think Hensel's applies, not even the stronger version of Hensel's

Comment: okay so try polynomial remainder theorem for prime squares ...

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to answer? I suspect your answer might be off topic.

Comment: Modelling $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$ as Witt vectors of length two over $\Bbb{F}_p$ felt somewhat natural in that $x_i^p$ then range over the set of Teichmüller representatives (parametrized by $\Bbb{F}_p$). In theory we get a system of equations over $\Bbb{F}_p$. Alas, the Witt vector arithmetic is rather kludgy to work with, and I could not make any headway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my programming is correct, of the first $40$ odd primes $p$ the only ones where not all 
$k$ are sums of three $p$'th powers mod $p^2$ are $3, 7, 11, 17$, and $59$.
For example, the cubes mod $9$ are $0, 1, 8$; and $4$ and $5$ are not sums of three of those mod $9$.

Comment: I believe your programming is correct. I have a not so savvy PC and could not do p = 59, but all others seems to agree with my result. I am interested in knowing something useful on a theoretical level about differentiating between those $p$ for which three p-th power are not enough and the other set of $p$.